# Is there a circumstance where $_POST is not an array?

Tags: php, post

This seems like a simple question but I'm having trouble finding an answer. Will there ever be a circumstance where the PHP [`$_POST`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) [superglobal](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) will not be an array? Is there a possibility of it being `null`? Thank you.

Comment: Just do `$_POST = null` and it's null. Other than that, it's an array.

Comment: In pure PHP, yes. In framework-ladden environments, it might be deliberately unset or an ArrayObject e.g.